# Curved ListView divider

Tags: android, listview, divider

I am trying to create a listview of photos. Problem is that I want my listview row to have curved divider.

I've tried getting custom imageview shape, but that wasn't working well because the divider was a straight line, and there was lots of white space.

Secondly i've tried to get divider as a .png but that also gave me nothing but lots of white space. So how could I achieve something like this (Yellow line is divider):

[image]

Comment: Unusual shapes like this are inherently difficult due to the fact that Views are always rectangular from the perspective of the system. Is there an alternative design that you are willing to settle for?

Comment: I am into programing just for few months, and this is first real challenge which I am doing for money. The client knows that I am newbie, he's webprogrammer himself, but I really don't want dissapoint him. Of course I can say that it is just to hard to draw it like this, but It would be way cooler if I could code UI like this. 

Any ways, maybe Overriding ListView's drawChild() method would help me achieve anything?

Comment: forget that question and use `divide and conquer method`: what you need is : custom listview + items in listview that overlap each other. so focus on overlapping views in list item. then creating listview by that trick and ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a simple idea:
Made a couple of "semy wavy" PNGs with transparent areas.
The 2 will be the upper and lower half (the curvature has to be small enough and the stroke wide enough to cut the wave in 2 halves longitudinally).

You'll end up with two rectangles (say a "header" and a footer).
When two rows are displayed, the top part of the second completes the curve of the first one.

Something like so:

[image] (upper part)

Your ImageView

[image] (lower part)

This is when 2 rows meet:

[image]

The black part represents the second row ImageView.

Well, maybe it's not as curvy as you would desire, but no even such a bad result, in my opinion.
It gives you the idea.

You can do a better artist work, if you make it more "metallic" using gradients.

**[EDIT]**

You might argue that the very first row and the last one would have a "cut" top and bottom, respectively.
Right observation.

But I just had an idea on how to "round" them too.

You can add a headerView with the **bottom** part and a footerView with the **top** part, and this closes the loop(s).

While these headers scroll with the rows... **les jeux sont fait**!

Comment: No... your **super** hero! ;)